# Irrational Conjugate

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I have irrational number:

$\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{2}$

It's has 3 conjugate numbers:

1. $\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{2}$
2. $-\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{2}$
3. $-\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{2}$

First variant - it's a standrart form for me. It's useful when you want to get equition without irrational denominator. But 2 and 3 cases... Why it's conjugate digits too?

Comment: what is the "digit"? why you call them digit ? (My English is terible)

Comment: How do you define "conjugate"?

Comment: however, conjugate is defined for complex values, Are you sure about "$\sqrt3-\sqrt2$"

Comment: 1) be more specific: why are you talking about "digit" instead of "number" ? 2) conjugation is defined for complex numbers ("the conjugate of a real number is itself" is used sometimes) 3) how did you get those results ?

Comment: @Renato Faraone 1)I'm sorry, my English is not perfect. I mean "irrational number" 2) I read about irrational conjugates discussion http://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-complex-conjugates-and-irrational-conjugates and don't unerstand well 3) I get those results from some intresting video about complex digits, but i'm sure it has this context, without complex values

Comment: Note that your second case is just $-1*(\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{2})$, so multiplying your first expression by this again yields a rational number. I'm not sure the third case could be called conjugate in the way you have used it...

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_element_%28field_theory%29

Comment: Indeed, your 3rd is the odd one out: it doesn't behave like a conjugate should (multiply it by your expression: is the result rational?)

Comment: @pjs36, You are right, third one out of my example! I realized, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For brevity let's call your original number $\alpha_0$, and the other three $\alpha_1$, $\alpha_2$, and $\alpha_3$.

Let's look first at the equation $(x-\alpha_0)(x-\alpha_1)=0$. This simplifies to $x^2-2\sqrt{3}\,x+1=0$, a quadratic not all of whose coefficients are rational.

However, something nice happens  when we look at the equation $(x-\alpha_0)(x-\alpha_1)(x-\alpha_2)(x-\alpha_3)=0$.  When you multiply out, you will find that this is a degree $4$ polynomial with integer coefficients.

It turns out that if $P(x)$ is any non-constant polynomial with rational coefficients, and $\alpha_0$ is a root of $P(x)=0$, then $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3$ are also roots of $P(x)=0$.  In that sense, the $\alpha_i$ kind of like to hang around together, just like $a+bi$ and $a-bi$.

Answer (score 1):

I don't feel this is what you are searching for but I'll try to explain:

Conjugation is an operation defined only for complex numbers and has various application, without getting too deep for any number defined as $z=a+ib$ it's complex conjugate is defined as $\bar z=a-ib$ and as you have already noticed $z\times \bar z \in \Bbb R$. Defining conjugation for real number on the other hand is not useful in any way so we usually define that for every real $x=a$ it's "conjugate" is $\bar x=a$ itself.

Now you have probably pointed out an analogy from an use of complex conjugation and "rationalization" (as translated on how we call it here in Italy) that we make because we usually prefer to have only integer numbers at the denominator:

$\frac {something}{\sqrt a+\sqrt b}=\frac {(something)(\sqrt a-\sqrt b)}{a-b}$

$\frac {something}{a+ib}=\frac {(something)(a-ib)}{a^2-b^2}$

So in that way it seems that the rule we applied was a kind of conjugation but remember that this is only a coincidence/analogy and doesn't gives us much.